# Why do I need "sendResponse" in one-time requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am looking at the code demonstration on this page: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

The code is this:

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
    sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
 });
```

I mostly understand the code, but one thing I don't understand is the "sendResponse". If I remove the `sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});` , the code still works fine which is good. But if I remove the `sendResponse` from `function(request, sender, sendResponse) {`, the extension doesn't carry through with the message passing. So basically i'm wondering why I need that parameter, even when I don't use it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `sendResponse()` if you're not going to use it.

Make sure you exclude the `sendResponse` callback argument:

```
// no sendResponse arg
function(request, sender) {
```

And remove your call:

```
// remove this
sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
```

And finally, don't try to log the farewell from the response since it won't exist:

```
// remove this
console.log(response.farewell);
```